# Sort Object Array by dependant property

Tags: javascript

I have an unsorted objects array with strings like this:

```
const unsortedArr =  [
  {
  id: "test13",
  startAfter: "test15"
  },
  {
  id: "test20",
  startAfter: "test5"
  },
  { 
  id: "test5",
  startAfter: "test1"
  },
  {
  id: "test15",
  startAfter: "test20"
  },
]
```

You get the idea.

I also have a start ID:     `const startId = "test1";`

With my start ID as the first value, I want to sort the array according to the "startAfter" property. Create a chronological chain, so to speak.

The result should look like this:

```
const sortedArr =  [
    {
    id: "test5",
    startAfter: "test1"
    },
    {
    id: "test20",
    startAfter: "test5"
    },
    {
    id: "test15",
    startAfter: "test20"
    },
    {
    id: "test13",
    startAfter: "test15"
    },
    ]
```

What is the easiest way to sort this array in JS?

Comment: I don't know that a traditional sorting algorithm would work for this. I would have a "currentID" that I would initialize to your startId, I would find the element with that startAfter value, and push that element to a new array, then set the currentID to the new id, and continue.

Comment: The first step will be to make something you can use to look up the objects by their `id` or `startAfter` (it's not 100% sure to me which you plan to use). Otherwise, you'll do a lot of searching through the array. Once you have that, loop through it to build the result array in the desired order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a linked list, but it lacks the possibility to locate an object by id in constant time. So I'd suggest creating a Map for that first, and then you can create the sorted array by looking up the next id from the current node:

```js
function sort(unsortedArr, startId) {
    const map = new Map(unsortedArr.map(o => [o.startAfter, o]));
    const sorted = [];
    for (let node = map.get(startId); node; node = map.get(node.id)) {
        sorted.push(node);
    }
    return sorted;
}

// Example run
const unsortedArr = [{id: "test13",startAfter: "test15"},{id: "test20",startAfter: "test5"},{ id: "test5",startAfter: "test1"},{id: "test15",startAfter: "test20"},];
const startId = "test1";
const sorted = sort(unsortedArr, startId);
console.log(sorted);
```